# Seeing white space below each grid

Tags: html, flexbox, css-selectors, grid, css-grid

(i) What is the problem?

I am seeing white space below each grid. I am certain its not grid gap. I am using grid-template-areas to display two columns in each row.

[Image of problem attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lISvA.jpg)

(ii) What am I doing?

Using **grid-template-areas** to display a grid.

(iii) What have  I tried?

I did try inspecting and turns out that my grid height is way more than the content itself.

```
 <div class="middle">
    <article class="headingMiddle">
      <h3>Breaking News</h3>
    </article>

    <article class="breaking breaking1">
      <h4>Democracy at Threat</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br />
        Officiis veritatis, placeat voluptas eum saepe optio iste
        <br />cumque vero repellendus corporis beatae repellat? Sint <br />
        blanditiis laudantium nostrum tempore velit mollitia <br />
        consectetur enim accusantium eum, nisi dolorem in <br />
        molestiae ipsam optio quos. Numquam obcaecati <br />placeat
        repudiandae ex quas, molestias nihil nobis officia?
      </p>
    </article>

    <article class="breaking breaking2">
      <h4>Who is the boss Kamala or Biden?</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br />
        Officiis veritatis, placeat voluptas eum saepe optio iste
        <br />cumque vero repellendus corporis beatae repellat? Sint <br />
        blanditiis laudantium nostrum tempore velit mollitia <br />
        consectetur enim accusantium eum, nisi dolorem in <br />
        molestiae ipsam optio quos. Numquam obcaecati <br />placeat
        repudiandae ex quas, molestias nihil nobis officia?
      </p>
    </article>

    <article class="breaking breaking3">
      <h4>If Social Media is censored, Media could be next?</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br />
        Officiis veritatis, placeat voluptas eum saepe optio iste
        <br />cumque vero repellendus corporis beatae repellat? Sint <br />
        blanditiis laudantium nostrum tempore velit mollitia <br />
        consectetur enim accusantium eum, nisi dolorem in <br />
        molestiae ipsam optio quos. Numquam obcaecati <br />placeat
        repudiandae ex quas, molestias nihil nobis officia?
      </p>
    </article>

    <article class="breaking breaking4">
      <h4>Ascent of fake news and polarization</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br />
        Officiis veritatis, placeat voluptas eum saepe optio iste
        <br />cumque vero repellendus corporis beatae repellat? Sint <br />
        blanditiis laudantium nostrum tempore velit mollitia <br />
        consectetur enim accusantium eum, nisi dolorem in <br />
        molestiae ipsam optio quos. Numquam obcaecati <br />placeat
        repudiandae ex quas, molestias nihil nobis officia?
      </p>
    </article>

    <article class="breaking breaking5">
      <h4>Black Lives Matter or No Lives Matter</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br />
        Officiis veritatis, placeat voluptas eum saepe optio iste
        <br />cumque vero repellendus corporis beatae repellat? Sint <br />
        blanditiis laudantium nostrum tempore velit mollitia <br />
        consectetur enim accusantium eum, nisi dolorem in <br />
        molestiae ipsam optio quos. Numquam obcaecati <br />placeat
        repudiandae ex quas, molestias nihil nobis officia?
      </p>
    </article>

    <article class="breaking breaking6">
      <h4>Climate Change is not a haox</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br />
        Officiis veritatis, placeat voluptas eum saepe optio iste
        <br />cumque vero repellendus corporis beatae repellat? Sint <br />
        blanditiis laudantium nostrum tempore velit mollitia <br />
        consectetur enim accusantium eum, nisi dolorem in <br />
        molestiae ipsam optio quos. Numquam obcaecati <br />placeat
        repudiandae ex quas, molestias nihil nobis officia?
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
```

and CSS is

```
.middle {
display: grid;
grid-template-areas:
"headingMiddle headingMiddle"
"breaking1 breaking2"
"breaking3 breaking4"
"breaking5 breaking6";
grid-area: middle;
justify-content: space-evenly;
border: 2px solid black;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
grid-column-gap: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser's dev tools has an inspector tool that'll tell you exactly what's creating the white space.

For Chrome, see: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/grid/

Comment: thanks for answer. yes I again inspected it shows thats its the length of the grid. so how to make sure that length of the grid is same as the content.

Comment: @DeveloperSam Do you have a demo? It's not possible to recreate this issue.

Comment: I have a attached a photo, but anyways, I got around this issue by using height: calc(100vh - 10px); I did this.